# How caching of pages use ionic 2?

Tags: dictionary, caching, typescript, ionic2, leaflet

Can I save the page status if I moved to new page?

I have a map and some objects on the map. I want if map is loaded, that all state saving if i moved new page and then I come back. That's it high-loaded process (+ loading image again). Use lealetjs

Thanks!

Comment: For multi view data i would thing of using some service to store and manage the shared data. If You'r concern is that images will be loaded again, maybe some solutions for caching them will help here. i.e. https://github.com/zyramedia/ionic-image-loader

Comment: I think in ionic 2, the page state of the pages getting pushed on 1 set of navigation stack, (i.e. until you set the root to another component again), is already saved. Also, in case of resources as well, if the resource is getting loaded from the same source, say an image, gets cached. But it might not be maintained across various sessions. You can check it out from browser => Inspect => Sources and Network tab.

Comment: @AdamSzmyd, yes, I use service, but If I moved before page and again map page - map is not initialize (if I not call of Initialization function).

However if I not use back button, but moved next page and before page - is all ok! Now I'll take care of everything (I'll try to change the actions of the back button). For the answer and the link - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

I change app architecture - I add two tabs (list elements page and map with markers). And when I opened map page use tabs - page loaded and it's Ok!

Explanation of work ionic:
If you use `navCtrl.pop()` - current page  will be deleted from memory. But If you can not use tabs - use `navCtrl.push()` new before page. And when user will want to return before page - `navCtrl.pop()` - delete current page, but before page will be cached. 
That is, from the user's point of view - it's back is already on the previous page, and from the point of view of the programmer - a new same page is being created.

And if user wants to move to before->before page, use navCtrl.popTo(index  of the desired page - you can use `this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex([yourPageNumber]));`